# I need to do an n x n block in Python to display "*" for that block

Tags: python

```
size = int(input("please enter an integer:"))
for row in range(size*1):
    print("*", end="")
print()
for column in range(1* size):
    print("*", end="")
print()
```

This is my code so far and I need it to print:
for 2

```
**
**
```

and for 7

```
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
*******
```

I have gotten it to print

```
**
**
```

for 2 but for 7 I just get

```
*******
*******
```

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to write this in many languages would use a nested loop. However, it is much easier in Python:

```py
for i in range(size):
    print('*' * size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the for loops since you want the number of lines to be equal to the number of columns:

```
size = int(input("please enter an integer:"))
for row in range(size):
    for col in range(size):
        print('*', end="")
    print()
```

PS: You don't really have to mulitply by 1 in `range`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the two loops to achieve what you desire.

You can do it the following three lines with two tricks:

- You can generate a string of n '*' with the command `"*" * size`, therefore you need a single loop
- The `for` loop does not need an index, that is not used, so  you can use `_`

The code looks like this:

```
size = int(input("please enter an integer:"))
for _ in range(size):
    print("*" * size)
```

Comment: `print((('*'*size)+'\n')*size)` - no need for loop at all

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to simply multiply strings - no loops:

```py
size = int(input("please enter an integer:"))
print((('*'*size)+'\n')*size)
```

enjoy :D :D :D